# HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH in Athena due to different order in struct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Full error

```
HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas. 
The types are incompatible and cannot be coerced. The column 'ein_verification' in table 'dynamodb_etl_dev.widget_user_snapshots' is declared as type 
'struct<status:string,unlocktimestamp:bigint,message:string,lastverifiedtimestamp:bigint,datelastverified:bigint>', but partition 'snapshot_time=2022-08-03T18%3A41' declared column 'ein_verification' as type 
'struct<status:string,unlocktimestamp:bigint,lastverifiedtimestamp:bigint,message:string,datelastverified:bigint>'.
```

It looks like the only difference is the order *message:string,lastverifiedtimestamp:bigint* is reversed but they are otherwise the same.

I know there are settings for updating the table definition and updating existing partitions with metadata from the table, but I'd like to understand why this is happening and possibly prevent it from happening at all.

Also it appears Athena is not trying to query the latest partition, as there is a new partitition with a more recent timestamp in this s3 bucket. I'm stuck on how to proceeed as I can run this job once and get a single partition and it works fine. But everytime so far that I run it a second time I get the error with struct out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to the partion error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241088/how-to-create-aws-glue-table-where-partitions-have-different-columns-hive-par) . I n particular, theres a comment on how to do it in terraform that helped me get it running